# Google api GetContacts Max Results Python

Tags: python, google-api

How do I increase the max results:

```
contacts_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(domain=domain)
myContacts = contacts_client.GetContacts(max_results=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
contacts_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(domain=domain)
query = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsQuery()
query.max_results = 100
myContacts = contacts_client.GetContacts(q=query)
```